# Tabela do editor de texto não está gravando no banco

Tags: php, wordpress, polymer, web-component

Tenho um editor de texto em um projeto, porém quando alguém usa a ferramenta de tabela no editor ele não grava a tabela no banco, grava somente o conteúdo da tabela. E quando é feito o download o texto vem sem a tabela, ficando sem formatação.

Estou usando o editor *Froala* como componente, projeto *wordpress*.

Comment: Você não possui nenhum filtro de tags html nesse campo na hora do insert no BD? se houver ele vai apagar a formtação.

Comment: @Wesley Reis, deixe mais informações sobre o seu problema para conseguirmos ajudá-lo. Se possível com trechos de código que ilustrem o seu problema.

Answer (score -1):

O problema no editor de texto foi resolvido adicionando CSS para as bordas da tabela.

Comment: isso é um comentário e não uma reposta para o problema, quando tiver reputação suficiente poderá deixar comentários na publicação até lá não insira comentários em campo de respostas.

Comment: @WMomesso Observe que quem respondeu é o autor da pergunta.

Comment: Eu vi mas mesmo assim não é uma resposta válida, para que ela se torne válida precisa ser editada com trechos de código e explicação de como resolveu, [como responder](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)